# iOS background bluetooth discovery stops on display off

Tags: ios, background, task

We are trying to monitor a Bluetooth LE device as a background task on iOS.

Everything is working fine, except the background task runs only when the display is turned on.

This is not what we want, because we want background monitoring while the phone is not in use.

We are searching for information about why and how apple does this, but there is nothing to be found.

Does anybody know if it's possible to keep running background tasks when the display is turned off?

Comment: If we use the timer then application will run maximum 10 min in background or Keep updating every sec allocate timer & check in timer function method whether application is running in background or foreground.

Comment: Have you specified BLE background mode? Which object is holding  your CBcentralManager instance? Is it a singleton such as your app delegate?  I have no issue with discovering devices with the display off.

Comment: Alright so it must be possible, we have a own class BluetoothMonitor and it contains the CBCentralManager object, we did not try singleton pattern yet. Did you implement it in the app delegate?

Comment: I created a separate singleton because it makes it easier to reuse than if it is tangled up in the app delegate.

Comment: Ok so you managed to skip the 10 minute background task limit AND discover duplicates while in background mode?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible - see the "Background Execution Modes" section of the [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html).  Your app must declare its background mode in its info.plist file, and your app will only be woken on a BTLE event.  Also, note that when you call scanForPeripheralsWithServices:, you must specify a list of services in which you are interested - if you use the default of `nil` your app will never be woken.